# How to generate a Buy It Now url for products?

Tags: magento-1.7, product

I am aware of the default Add to cart url (`/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=1`), however I also want a Buy it now url that will add to cart then redirect the user to the checkout page (e.g. `/checkout/onepage/`).

A co-worker suggested `echo $_product->getData('buyitnowurl')` but that just generates the product's url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is implement an observer which sets the redirectUrl, so you process this execution path:

```
\Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction
public function addAction()
{
    // ...
    try {
        // ...
        $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
        if ($url) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        } else {
            $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
        }
```

So your URL is taken from the session and it is redirected to the checkout.

I think the easiest is, when you hook into `checkout_cart_product_add_after`, so you can be sure, that the item was added. You just have to add a parameter you can check in the URL, so you know it was a "Buy now" url.